# How to set default PS1 value for interactive python?

Tags: python, interactive, prompt

I'm attempting to colorize my python interpreter to help visually separate text noise.
So if I start interactive python it gives me plain text. I can do this:

```
import sys

sys.ps1 = "\033[0;34m>>> \033[0m"
sys.ps2 = "\033[1;34m... \033[0m"
```

However if I exit the interpreter and go back in the values revert to their default, which isn't surprising in the slightest. My question is how would I save these values and use them as the default?

Comment: fourth line is obviously meant to be ps2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the environment variable `PYTHONSTARTUP` is defined when Python starts (in interactive mode), Python will read and execute that file.  Look at the `ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES` section of [this document](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html) for more information.

So if you put your `sys.ps1` commands into `~/.pythonrc.py` and pointed `PYTHONSTARTUP` at that file...

```
export PYTHONSTARTUP=~/.pythonrc.py
```

...you would be all set.

You may also want to check out [ipython](http://ipython.org/), which is a Python interactive interpreter with all sorts of fancy features and customization possibilities.

Comment: So add a PYTHONSTARTUP variable to my bashrc containing the file I want to autoload?

Comment: Sure.  You could place it in either you `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`, and don't forget that you need to `export` it (as in my example).

Comment: Bingo! I got it working before you updated your reply. Thanks a lot for the info... now on to syntax coloring the entire thing.